# Where to find API level option in Delphi Xe5, Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Where to find API level option in Delphi Xe5 to target specific devices, Android?
Apps built directly in Android studio supports 5500 devices but app built in firemonkey only supports 3500 device, I dunno why? I cant find option to setup API level for Android SDK that might increase number of supported devices, any help are appreciated?

Comment: There are some specific requirements for firemonkey, please read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)

Comment: FireMonkey applications require certain CPU and GPU types and capabilities, and changing the API level isn't going to change those hardware requirements. As @whosrdaddy said, read the system requirements in the documentation. (Although it won't help with what you're trying to do, you can change the API level by expanding the Android target in the Project Manager, right-clicking Android, and choosing "Properties" from the context menu.)

Comment: Android store states that min API requirements is 9+, but app is working properly on Level 8 also, Is there any posibility to change minimual API requirement in Delphi, I have tried to google for this but come up nothing, any help?

Comment: I got it, I have modified AndroidManifest.xml, now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AndroidManifest.template.xml file within your Delphi project directory and then change the "android:minSdkVersion" from "%minSdkVersion%" to whatever version you want to be as minimum. Then also make sure to change the "android:targetSdkVersion" from "%targetSdkVersion%" to "26" because this is a must for Google Play Store starting November 2018.

Also make sure that you have Android API 26 selected withen the Delphi SDK Manager Properties.